# How to use a slug in Vapor 3

Tags: swift, vapor

How would I go about generating a slug for a `SQLiteModel` object, and using it in Leaf for Vapor 3? My goal is to provide a search engine friendly link to the detail page of my model (for example, `/tag/swift/` vs. `/tag/0/`), rather than link using the `id`.

I found the `Parameter` protocol, which means my model has a `uniqueSlug` property. Unfortunately using it in Leaf `#(model.uniqueSlug)` doesn't work.

**Here's my leaf code:**

```
  #for(tag in tags) {
      <a class="tag" href="tag/#(tag.id)">#(tag.name)</a>
  }
```

**Here's my model:**

```swift
final class Tag: SQLiteModel, Codable {
  var id: Int?
  var name: String
  var description: String

  init(id: Int? = nil, name: String, description: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
  }
}

extension Tag: Migration { }

extension Tag: Content { }

extension Tag: Parameter { }
```

**I also tried adding a computed property to the model:**

```swift
var slug: String {
  return "test"
}
```

That also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your route code as well, please? Also, when you say it "doesn't work", can you post the actual html?

Comment: @Nick Sorry, I meant that there is no output (an empty string). It looks like `uniqueSlug` isn't accessible from Leaf.

I asked on the Vapor slack channel, and was told to look at https://github.com/brokenhandsio/SteamPress for an example of what I want.

I was looking for something like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify.

I haven't looked at the SteamPress code yet, but I may eventually open an issue on Leaf asking for a built in `slugify` tag.

Comment: you can omit specifying the Codable protocol on Tag class since Content conforms to it already.